# Appcelerator Titanium iOS Module in XCode gives error: Cannot find interface declaration for 'TiModule'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I created an Appcelerator iOS Module via CLI like this:
(`appc new -n moduleName --id com.my.moduleId`)

Beside the `ComModulenameModule` I have created the `ViewProxy` and `View` `.h` and `.m` files so I can use native views.

I haven't written a single line of code, and the compiler already gives me the error:
`Cannot find interface declaration for 'TiModule', superclass of 'ComModulenameModule'`.

Why is that happening? The module was generated via CLI, so it should have all the structure to deal with the `Titanium framework`. It should `"come from factory"`.

```
#import "TiModule.h"
@interface ComModulenameModule : TiModule { //Cannot find interface declaration for 'TiModule', superclass of 'ComModulenameModule'
```

Same error goes for the `TiUIView`.
By the way, I think the imports are correct.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you build the module? https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Quick+Start and using `appc run -p ios -b` works fine. I've create a new module like you did and added the example files from the `Add a view proxy and view` example in the link above. Building works fine, not have to include anything else

Comment: Hi @miga! Thanks for the feedback. I did exactly like the example in the `Quick Start` and I have this issue. I cannot even build it (with `appc run -p ios -b` or `appc run -p ios --build-only`), and it crashes. `[ERROR] [xcode-sim]  CompileC build/moduleName.build/Release-iphonesimulator/moduleName.build/Objects-normal/i386/ComModulenameModule.o Classes/ComModulenameModule.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler`.
The compiler from XCode gives the error, and the build crashes.

Comment: Strange. I don't have any problems runnign the example code. Can you add you appc/ti version, xcdoe and osx version please? Maybe the problem is somewhere hidden there.

Comment: `Mac OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave)`, 
`XCode 11.3.1`, 
`Appc  CLI 8.0.0`, 
`Appc 6.0.0.201812040934`

Comment: appc 6 = titanium sdk 6? That is not supoorted anymore. Please update to 9.0.3 or at least 8.3.1. That could be a reason why it is failing since you are using the latest CLI

Comment: Oh Sorry, I am using Titanium SDK 8.3.1.GA - in the other comment I was talking about the Appcelerator Studio version per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that fixed it, was to format my Mac and reinstall everything.
I tried creating a new user, tried another version of XCode, nothing. The only resolution was formatting.